# How is the first character of BIN collation sorted?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to reproduce the logic behind the `BIN` collation in my application code. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143350(v=sql.105).aspx:

> Older SQL Server binary collations compared the first character as WCHAR, followed by a byte-by-byte comparison.

How does "comparing as WCHAR" differ from a "byte-by-byte comparison"?

Please provide sample data that results in different sorting for WCHAR and byte-by-byte sorting.

Comment: Maybe it will be [helpful](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110911/latin1-general-bin-performance-impact-when-changing-the-database-default-collati)

Comment: @lad2025 unfortunately, it doesn't seem to explain how WCHAR sorting differs from byte-by-byte sorting.